# Component Scan not scanning sub packages

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data-jpa, component-scan

I have encountered a strange problem. I am under the impression that component scan scans the sub packages recursively if a top level package is specified for scanning.

My repositories and entities are the maven dependency of the project. They live under the package name com.foo.bar.xyz and my application config is under package com.foo.bar. When I write `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.foo.bar")`, along with `@EnableJpaRepositories`it gives an error that repository bean not found.

However when I specify a top level repository package like `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = com.foo.bar.xyz)` , along with component scan as above, it detects the repository just fine.

Now is this happening only because the repositories and entities are being injected as maven dependency? So does the recursive part of component scan, scans the sub packages or the subdirectories?

Comment: FYI, I made it work my specifically mentioning the packages to scan inside the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Now is this happening only because the repositories and entities are
>   being injected as maven dependency?

- No it is not

> So does the recursive part of component scan, scans the sub packages
>   or the subdirectories?

- Yes component scan does search recursively in sub packages

To elaborate here `@ComponentScan` is intended to search all classes having `@Component` or its sub types like `@Controller` whereas to enable Spring Data JPA by annotating the PersistenceContext class with the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation and to configure the base packages that are scanned when Spring Data JPA creates implementations for the repository interfaces. Hence the need for declaring the base package information for both `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`